# How to run golang test on travis with filesystem permission (beside sudo, if possible?)

Tags: permissions, travis-ci, sudo

I am trying to build my golang cli project with TravisCI. One of the problem found is when running test which create files, I got permission error.

[image]

But when trying to run the test with sudo, it changed to `sudo: go: command not found`

Here is the error snippet from travis:

[image]

Anyone can help with a solution?

Notes:

1. I dont want to change my test to use sudo in the code, because later when it is used the user should decide by himself whether to use sudo or not

Comment: gimme (the tool travis uses to install go) installs go for the user, not for root. Looking at the gimme script, the `go` executable is located in `${GIMME_VERSION_PREFIX}/go${version}.${GIMME_OS}.${arch}`

Comment: Never use sudo as the magical "make this happen" hammer. Just fix your FS right beforehand.

Comment: @Volker it is working on my local and others (if permission is accessbile). And the cli indeed has some function to create dir. Just on travis I cant find that option to allow permission except sudo. Probably, you can give a solution that doesn't require sudo? that would be great!

Comment: Good suggestion though, gonna update the title to make it less misleading

Comment: I think your Go bin directory is not in sudo's PATH or secure_path for sudo - see /etc/sudoers

Comment: @AndrewW.Phillips yes it seems, but it is running on travis, which I have no control of

Comment: You could use sudo on chmod.

Comment: @Volker the failing one is the create directory/files, not the binary itself. Gonna update the question to add more snippets

Comment: And I am not talking about the go binary I suggested to chmod the folder you try to create files in to allow that.

Comment: Don't paste images of text!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question

Compiling from the comments, I tried 2 options

The first is to update the current working directory permission, with `chmod 777 .` (yes I set all, dont want to really bother with travis specific behavior), but turns out it doesn't work. Don't know for sure the cause this time, probably the dynamically generated binary also have permission issue

The solution that works for me is reading the `go` binary path, then re-run it as sudo, as shown below

```
script: 
  - GO_EXECUTABLE_PATH=$(which go)
  - echo $GO_EXECUTABLE_PATH
  - sudo $GO_EXECUTABLE_PATH test ./...
```